# Deployment error message in Jeveloper

Tags: soa, jdeveloper, bpel

I am deploying my BPEL project on Web-logic server through my JDeveloper 11g. its working fine. but when I selected my  different environment for deployment(new one) then I got the following error.
  Error is due to one of my BPEL prcess "TaskProcess1".
but the same setup when I deploy to my own server its deploying and running very fine.

```
 code=500
[04:53:57 PM] Error deploying archive sca_RegistrationUpload_rev24.0.jar to partition "default" on server DAMS_Batch_Server1 [urasvr140.uradevt.gov.sg:8001, Cluster:DAMS_Batch_Cluster]  
[04:53:57 PM] HTTP error code returned [500]
[04:53:57 PM] Error message from server:
#;There was an error deploying the composite on DAMS_Batch_Server1: Operation failed - Member(Id=1, Timestamp=2011-06-02 15:25:57.428, Address=172.16.10.45:8088, MachineId=46637, Location=site:uradevt.gov.sg,machine:urasvr140,process:3968, Role=WeblogicServer):Error occurred during deployment of component: TaskProcess1 to service engine: implementation.bpel, for composite: RegistrationUpload: ORABPEL-01005
#;
#;Failed to compile bpel generated classes.
#;failure to compile the generated BPEL classes for BPEL process "TaskProcess1" of composite "default/RegistrationUpload!24.0*soa_f19c6537-e518-4c05-940c-688c1ddb2593"
#;The class path setting is incorrect.
#;Ensure that the class path is set correctly. If this happens on the server side, verify that the custom classes or jars which this BPEL process is depending on are deployed correctly. Also verify that the run time is using the same release/version. 
#;; .  Please see the server diagnostic logs on DAMS_Batch_Server1 for details.
```

Please let me know if any suggestion you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a dependant jar file that you are accessing from your bpel process?

Check the log files on the server for the soa_server. It will give you more information as to why it failed at the server

Comment: Yes I checked but SOA_server1 log is not having any information.... no luck for this...when I comment that code its works for me, it means something its required at class level. but not able to set... one more think I have created this process at 11.1.1.3 and deploying the process on 11.1.1.4. but other than this all processed getting deployed....so  I dont think so this may be an issue....

Comment: "Also verify that the run time is using the same release/version."  This quote is from the error trace you posted.  I suspect that will be your problem as oracle code tends to check versions when doing deployments, and lots of other things.